# 2 SSL, 3 web sites, 1 IP in IIS 7.5

Tags: facebook, iis, ssl, iis-7.5, ssl-certificate

I am developping facebook apps therefore i need to setup ssl certificates and i must say that it's not my thing.

I have :

a) 1 IP address

b) 2 ssl certificates from startssl for app1.site1.fr and app1.site2.fr

c) https://app1.site1.fr  with a certificate named : *.apps.site1.fr, hostname ok

d) http://site1.fr with the same certificate named : *.apps.site1.fr, hostname ok

e) https://app1.site2.fr  i would like to use an other certificate named *.app1.site2.fr, hostname ok

As I understand, if i want app2.site2.fr or app2.site1.fr, i need a wildcard certificate but that is not what i want.

When i try to setup the (e) app1.site2.fr, iis gives me a warning message : 
"At least one other site is using the same https binding and the binding is configurate with an other certificate. Are you sure..."

I think that it is not a hostname problem as there are 3 different hostnames... But i don't understand why iis tells me that's a binding problem ?

Could you help me to put a different certificate on (e) than on (c) and (d) please ?
Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can only have 1 SSL certificate per IP address in IIS. There are a couple of ways to solve this problem.

1) Assign another IP address to the server and and configure the second certificate for that site (although it sounds like you can not do this).

or

2) Combine all sites in to one SAN (Subject Alternative Name) Certificate so you can have multiple SSL sites on 1 IP address using 1 certificate.